# Extracting long long int numbers from string and putting them in vector

Tags: c++, string, vector

Here is what I implemented form last time and this code is working for most of my test cases but it is not working for these cases.

```
#include <climits>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

long long ConvertStringToNumber(std::string number) {
  long long int finalNumber = 0;
  bool isNegative = false;
  int i = 0;
  if (number.at(0) == '-') {
    isNegative = true;
    i++;
  }
  for (; i < number.length(); i++) {
    if (number.at(i) < '0' || number.at(i) > '9') {
      throw std::invalid_argument("Some error...");
    }
    if (finalNumber >
        (std::numeric_limits<long long int>::max() - (number.at(i) - '0')) / 10) {
      throw std::overflow_error("Input string contains a number that is too large!!!");
      throw std::range_error("Number is too large");
    }
    finalNumber = finalNumber * 10 + (number.at(i) - '0');
  }
  return isNegative ? -finalNumber : finalNumber;
}

std::vector<long long int> NumbersInString(std::string s) {
  std::vector<long long int> numbers;
  std::string currentNumber = "";
  bool isNumber = true;
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    char c = s.at(i);
    if ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || c == '-') {

      currentNumber += c;
      isNumber = true;
    } else if (isNumber) {
      if (!(currentNumber.size() == 0) &&
          ((currentNumber != "-" && currentNumber.at(0) == '-') ||
           (currentNumber.at(0) >= '0' && currentNumber.at(0) <= '9'))) {

        if (i == s.length() || ((s.at(i) < 'a' || s.at(i) > 'z') &&
                                (s.at(i) < 'A' || s.at(i) > 'Z'))) {
          try {
            long long int number = ConvertStringToNumber(currentNumber);
            numbers.push_back(number);
          } catch (std::domain_error &k) {
            // skip it
          }
        }
      }
      currentNumber = "";
      isNumber = false;
    }
  }

  if (isNumber && !currentNumber.empty()) {
    try {
      long long int number = ConvertStringToNumber(currentNumber);
      numbers.push_back(number);
    } catch (std::domain_error &e) {
    }
    // skip again
  }
  return numbers;
}

int main() {
  std::string input;
  std::cout << "Enter a string: ";
  std::getline(std::cin, input);
  try {
    std::vector<long long int> numbers = NumbersInString(input);
    if (numbers.empty()) {
      std::cout << "The entered string does not contain any numbers!\n";

    } else {
      std::cout << "Numbers within the string: ";

      for (long long int number : numbers) {
        std::cout << number << " ";
      }
      std::cout << std::endl;
    }
  } catch (std::overflow_error &e) {
    std::cout << "PROBLEM: " << e.what() << std::endl;
  } catch (std::range_error &k) {
    std::cout << "Exception with message:" << k.what();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Can someone please give explanation and help for these cases here is the output:
Enter a string: -123 123-123 123- 123
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
what():  Some error...
Aborted

=== Code Exited With Errors ===
Here is the correct output:
-123 123-123 123- 123

and
Enter a string: Ovo je 123456789012345678901234563 -90 test.
PROBLEM: Input string contains a number that is too large!!!

=== Code Execution Successful ===

But output needs to be: Number too big!
Can someone explain how to catch the exception and write different message then?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Since you have expectations for the function, you can use a debugger to step through the function and watch where the function violates your expectations. That'll be the bug. Now if you didn't have expectations, finding what's wrong is a lot harder.

Comment: What is the difference between the character sequences "123xy" and "327,"? The code in the question doesn't distinguish between them, simply treating any non-digit character as the end of a valid number.

Comment: For school (or similar) assignments or exercises, please always include the actual assignment/exercise text (copy-pasted as text) in the question. It always helps to see the actual requirements and limitations for it.

Comment: Anytime somebody brings up `long long int` as a type there is a very good chance they want arbitrary-precision integer types instead. Which are implemented as (effectively) vectors of numbers in a chosen base. (base 10 if you store one digit per element, but could be base 2^32 if you use a `vector<uint32_t>`)

Comment: As for ways to make it easier to test and debug, try to extract *words* first, and use a separate function for the conversion of the numbers. The smaller and specialized and simpler each function is, the easier it will be not only to debug, but also to understand, test and maintain.

Comment: Ok I will try doing it

Comment: Extending on Botje's comment, an alternative to "big Numbers" is there's often a sneaky trick you can use to eliminate the need for large numbers, huge amounts of storage, or enormous runtimes. The point of the problem is to find this trick.

Comment: Don't forget that if they are just asking for a list of numbers, you don't need to convert them to things that you could do calculations with -- just store them as strings. If necessary, clean them up by removing leading zeroes. You can even ditch your inProgress (current number string is empty/not empty) and isNegative variables.

Comment: Using regular expressions for this would be simpler: https://regex101.com/r/cTjUzB/1

Comment: If you are using C++11 or later, consider using `std::stoll()` to read the integral value - at the least, you'll be able to simplify your code (which often makes it easier to get right).

Comment: Here is the updated version, can someone explain these problems I wrote there?